# Join tables by stitching columns, without making a cartesian product

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a formula or a trick to join tables by just stitching the columns together, without making a cartesian product?

For example, so that:

```
select 
    *
from 
    generate_series(1,3) a
??
    generate_series(10,11) b
??
    generate_series(21,24) c
```

would give:

```
a       b       c
------  ------  ------
1       10      21
2       11      22
3       (null)  23
(null)  (null)  24
```

given a mystery `??` operator.

I actually have a few sub-selects that I'd like to stitch together in this way. They may not have the same number of rows. The `generate_series()` above is just a way to get some sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the option `with ordinality` to generate a row number for each row from `generate_series()`. Then do a `full outer join` base on the row number:

```
select a.a, b.b, c.c
from generate_series(1,3) with ordinality a (a,rn)
  full outer join generate_series(10,11) with ordinality b (b, rn) using (rn)
  full outer join generate_series(21,24) with ordinality c (c, rn) using (rn)
```

this returns:

```
a | b  | c 
--+----+---
1 | 10 | 21
2 | 11 | 22
3 |    | 23
  |    | 24
```

---

If your source isn't a `generate_series()` then you need to add a `row_number()` to each sub-select:

```
select ...
from (
   select ...,  
          row_number() over (order by ...) as rn
   from table_one
) as a (..., rn)
  full outer join (
    select ...,  
           row_number() over (order by ...) as rn
    from table_two
  ) as b (..., rn) using (rn)
....
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. I had some `select distinct`, so I put one more level of nesting: `full join (select *, row_number() over () as rn from (select distinct ...) a) as ... using (rn)`